# Prime Factors displayed in multiplication format

Tags: c, function, prime-factoring

This is for an assignment so I'll just post the question details with my code right below it so you guys can follow easier than if I were to explain the problem myself.

Q) Any integer above 1 is either a prime number, or can be made by multiplying prime numbers together. For example: 16 = 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 = (2^4) 17 = (17^1) 18 = 2 x 3 x 3 = (2^1) x (3^2) Write a C program, primeFactor.c, that asks the user for an integer number greater than 1 and displays the product of its prime factors.

A Sample interaction is as follow:

Enter a valid number (>1): 18

18 = 1 x (2^1) x (3^3)

Enter a valid number (>1): 0

Invalid number.

Enter a valid number (>1): 19

19 = 1 x (19^1)

```
int readNum(int num)
{
    if (num <= 1)
    {
        return printf("Invalid Number.");
    }
    else
    {
        return printf("%i = ", num);
    }
}

int pcount = 0;
bool isPrime(int prime)
{
    bool p_flag = false;

    for(int i = 2; i < prime; i++)
    {
        if(prime % i == 0)
        {
            pcount += 1;
        }
    }
    if (pcount > 0)
    {
        p_flag = false;
    }
    else if (pcount == 0)
    {
        p_flag = true;
    }

    return p_flag;
}

int findPrimeCount(int num, int prime)
{
    int freq = 1;

    printf("1 ");
    for(prime = 2; prime < num; prime++)
    {
        freq = 1;
        while((num % prime) == 0)
        {
            printf(" * (%i ^ %i)", prime, freq);
            num = num / prime;
            freq++;
        }
    }

    if(num != 1)
    {
        printf(" * (%i ^ 1)", num);
    }

    return num;
}

int main(void)
{
    int number = 0;

    printf("Enter a valid number (>1): ");
    scanf("%i", &number);

    readNum(number);

    if(isPrime(number) == 1)
    {
        printf("1 * (%i ^ 1)", number);
    }
    else if (isPrime(number) == 0)
    {
        findPrimeCount(number, 2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Right now I guess I'm stuck in that if I input the number 64 the output will be:

64 = 1 * (2^1) * (2^2) * (2^3) * (2^4) * (2^5) * (2^6)

where I want the output to be just:

64 = 1 * (2^6)

I'm not sure how  I would go about truncating the string outputs before that or possibly even avoiding printing that whole thing out altogether. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `findPrimeCount` function, just put the `print` statement outside of your `while` loop so it only prints the `factor^highestFreq`:

```
int findPrimeCount(int num, int prime)
{
    int freq = 1;

    printf("1 ");
    for(prime = 2; prime < num; prime++)
    {
        freq = 1;
        while((num % prime) == 0)
        {

            num = num / prime;
            freq++;
        }
        // only print the last iteration
        // subtract 1 to frequency to equalize
        // the last freq++.
        freq--;
        // filter out num^0
        if(freq > 0)
        {
            printf(" * (%i ^ %i)", prime, freq);
        }
    }

    if(num != 1)
    {
        printf(" * (%i ^ 1)", num);
    }

    return num;
}
```

For input = 64 outputs:

```
64 = 1  * (2 ^ 6)
```

input = 46 outputs:

```
46 = 1  * (2 ^ 1) * (23 ^ 1)
```

Comment: In the case if number = 46 for example, this is the output:

46 = 1  * (2 ^ 1) * (3 ^ 0) * (4 ^ 0) * (5 ^ 0) * (6 ^ 0) * (7 ^ 0) * (8 ^ 0) *                                                                                             (9 ^ 0) * (10 ^ 0) * (11 ^ 0) * (12 ^ 0) * (13 ^ 0) * (14 ^ 0) * (15 ^ 0) * (16                                                                                             ^ 0) * (17 ^ 0) * (18 ^ 0) * (19 ^ 0) * (20 ^ 0) * (21 ^ 0) * (22 ^ 0) * (23 ^ 1                                                                                            )

Comment: @NinoBrown good catch! I updated my answer to add an `if` to weed out those `num^0`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @NinoBrown glad I could help!